# MPMediaItem to AVAsset to .MP3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I grab the audio data from an MPMediaItem (iTunes song) and put it in an AVAsset.  How do I turn my AVAsset into an .MP3 file that can be stored to disk?

Comment: I don't think that you can, wouldn't that cause copyright issues?

Comment: yes u can, and there is no issue, DRMed songs dont return a URL and thus u cant create an AVAsset from it, others you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, yes you can do this..... check out this great article that shows you how to use an AVAssetWriter to write out the data whilst reading...

[Article here.](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/)

Comment: @Daniel can you give a reference to how this can be done with only a reader?

Comment: @NickHolt check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812394/ios-5-0-crash-when-reading-data-from-an-avas‌​setreaderoutput/8524117#8524117  i put code in my answer that does just that