# How to convert CMSampleBufferRef to NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata, cmsamplebufferref

How do you convert CMSampleBufferRef to NSData?

I've managed to get the data for an `MPMediaItem` by following Erik Aigner's answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656124/mpmediaitems-raw-song-data), however the data is of type `CMSampleBufferRef`.

I know CMSampleBufferRef is a struct and is defined in the [CMSampleBuffer Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMSampleBuffer/Reference/reference.html) in the iOS Dev Library, but I don't think I fully understand what it is. None of the CMSampleBuffer functions seem to be an obvious solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go this works for audio sample buffer which is what you are looking at, and if you want to look at the whole process (getting all audio data from MPMediaItem into a file check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812394/ios-5-0-crash-when-reading-data-from-an-avassetreaderoutput) question

```
CMSampleBufferRef ref=[output copyNextSampleBuffer];
        // NSLog(@"%@",ref);
        if(ref==NULL)
            break;
        //copy data to file
        //read next one
        AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
        NSMutableData *data=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
        CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(ref, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);
        // NSLog(@"%@",blockBuffer);



        for( int y=0; y<audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y++ )
        {
            AudioBuffer audioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[y];
            Float32 *frame = (Float32*)audioBuffer.mData;


            [data appendBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize];



        }


        CFRelease(blockBuffer);
        CFRelease(ref);
        ref=NULL;
        blockBuffer=NULL;
        [data release];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: I'm still a bit lost and very noob on this stuff.  What is 'output' defined to be?

Comment: @jangelo42 Check the link i provide in the second line (its a full solution not just a fragment), output is AVAssetReaderOutput

Comment: How to convert video samples to `NSData`?

Comment: @prabhu it does that in the for loop

Comment: `AudioBuffer` is for audio right. its ok. I think I found a way. can you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078336/cmsamplebuffergetdatabuffer-returns-nil-value-cocoa-swift and let me know if anything is missing. Bugging my mind for the last few days. couldn't find anything related to it online.