# IOS - How to write AVAsset to file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, save, avasset

I am working with an app now that streams data from a web url. I am able to implement the streaming using AVAsset and AVPlayer as its player. Now, what I want to do is to save the streamed bytes from AVAsset to a music file in local. It's basically writing AvAsset to a music file. What I have in mind is converting AVAsset to NSData but I think this one is not possible.

How can I achieve this? Is this possible?

Comment: If its just about saving the asset as an audio file, check :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8524117/524719 . You can also check:  http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/

Comment: @BrianChristo but I had an error regarding the reader. AVAssetReader can't have a web url. It cannot initialize an instance of AVAssetReader with an asset of non-local URL.